# Quickbook integration and getting access token

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am using the quickbook php sdk. I am facing the problem to get a token

```
   $dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
          'auth_mode' => 'oauth2',
          'ClientID' => "XX",
          'ClientSecret' => "XX",
          'RedirectURI' => "http://localhost/naik/",
          'scope' => "com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting",
          'baseUrl' => "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com"
    ));

    $OAuth2LoginHelper = $dataService->getOAuth2LoginHelper();

    $url = $OAuth2LoginHelper->getAuthorizationCodeURL();

    header('Location: '.$url);
```

As per their documation i have to write the location to the url. When i run this code in my controller it does not show anything

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through the OAuth flow to get the access token.

This kicks off the OAuth flow. The access token is handed back to you as part of the redirect back to your site. Documentation:

[https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/0085_develop_quickbooks_apps/0004_authentication_and_authorization/connect_from_within_your_app](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/00_quickbooks_online/2_build/10_authentication_and_authorization/10_oauth_2.0)